# RecyclerView not showing data until turn off and turn on screen

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app that shows in a RecyclerView an image and a text that comes from firebase.
When I open the application the recyclerview does not appear but if I turn off and then turn on the screen the recyclerview appears correctly with the image and text obtained from firebase. I need help please

ViewHolder:

```
public class ViewHolderServicio extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
View mView;
public ViewHolderServicio(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;

}

public void setDetails(Context ctx, String nombreServicio, String imagenPerfil) {
    TextView mNombreServicio = mView.findViewById(R.id.NombreServicio);
    ImageView mImagenPerfil = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewServicio);

    mNombreServicio.setText(nombreServicio);
    Picasso.get().load(imagenPerfil).into(mImagenPerfil);

    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class ModelServicio {
String idUsuario, nombreServicio, descripcion, imagenPerfil;

public ModelServicio(){}

public String getIdUsuario() {
    return idUsuario;
}

public void setIdUsuario(String idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public String getNombreServicio() {
    return nombreServicio;
}

public void setNombreServicio(String nombreServicio) {
    this.nombreServicio = nombreServicio;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getImagenPerfil() {
    return imagenPerfil;
}

public void setImagenPerfil(String imagenPerfil) {
    this.imagenPerfil = imagenPerfil;
}
}
```

class activity:

```
public class DetalleServicio extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView RVbot;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelServicio, ViewHolderServicio> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelServicio> options;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_servicio);

    RVbot = findViewById(R.id.RVBot);
    RVbot.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RVbot.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Servicios");
    mostrarDatos();
}

private void mostrarDatos() {
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelServicio>().setQuery(mRef, ModelServicio.class).build();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelServicio, ViewHolderServicio>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderServicio holder, int position, @NonNull ModelServicio model) {
            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getNombreServicio(), model.getImagenPerfil());
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolderServicio onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.servicioitem, viewGroup, false);
            ViewHolderServicio viewHolder = new ViewHolderServicio(itemView);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };
    RVbot.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    RVbot.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to move `RVbot.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);` right after `RVbot.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));`? Does it work this way?

Comment: Yes, it was my first attempt but it did not work

Comment: Why do you say that? Did get an error?

Comment: i mean, the same thing happens. The recyclerview does not appear until I turn off and then turn on the screen, without errors

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after calling an Adapter?

Comment: But did you do it afer RVbot.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);?